# Visual Studio Apache Tools for Cordova - Module is not defined, Require is not defined

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

I am getting errors of "module is not defined" and "require is not defined" when attempting to build a brand new Cordova app with the Media and File plugins included. I created a brand new project, added those two plugins, and was immediately unable to build. Build works fine without the plugins.

I am also getting a "File.requestAllPaths - We seem to be missing some stuff :("

I have cleaned the Cordova cache and restarted VS13 (Community) and still have the errors. What could I be doing wrong or missing?

Comment: Could you try a clean build of your project and check if that solves the issue?

Comment: Please post build output message and if it does not contain much information then turn-on diagnostic log, go to Tools --> Options --> Projects and Solutions --> diagnostic (under output verbosity dropdown) and re-build the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-did a Cordova cache clean, then did a clean & build and these issues went away. "File.requestAllPaths - We seem to be missing some stuff :(" is from the emulator not supporting certain APIs.